# Select rows which have a field in common with another row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `products` and `postings`. A `product` is a consumer product (ex. iPhone X), and a `posting` is a listing for a product on an online marketplace (ex. eBay posting). A single product has zero or more associated postings.

Is there any way to select only postings which have a "sibling"? ie. Select all postings whose `product` column is equal to *any other postings'* `product` column.

```sql
SELECT * FROM postings a
INNER JOIN products b ON a.product = b.id
WHERE COUNT(b) > 0
```

Comment: Can any listing NOT have a product associated with it?  Do listings have a unique ID column, too?  What happens when you use your current query?  Also, if you want non-unique, you'd probably want to make your constraint > 1 since that will result in two or more of the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering your inner join should only do the trick, but in case I am missing something you can try this

```
With a as 
(
SELECT a.*,b.*, count(*) over(Partition by b.id) cnt 
FROM postings a
INNER JOIN products b ON a.product = b.id
)
Select * from a where cnt > 0
```

Comment: That's the feature I'm looking for! SQL never disappoints. I appreciate the help, it's saved me a good chunk of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want *postings*, then I would suggest:

```
select p.*
from postings p
where exists (select 1
              from postings p2
              where p2.product = p.product and
                    p2.posting_id <> p.posting_id
             );
```

Or, use window functions like this:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             count(*) over (partition by p.product) as cnt
      from postings p
     ) p
where cnt > 1;
```

Note that these do not require the `products` table, because the product information is available in postings.